# How many bytes does a derived type (in Fortran) occupy? Are the locations contiguous? And a pointer to a derived type?

Tags: pointers, types, fortran

I could not find this anywhere, and even if it could be trivial I wanna be sure I have well understood. I have 4 questions (strictly related):

1)If I define a derived type in fortran like this

```
    TYPE :: node
       INTEGER :: int
       REAL :: REALfirst
       REAL :: REALsecond
    END TYPE
    TYPE(node)  :: var
    allocate(var)
```

After the above allocation it occupies 4 byte for the integer and other 8 for the 2 single precision reals, for a total of 12 bytes. Are they located continuously in memory? And how does the computer store the information about the type of variables?I guess it needs some extra memory for saving that.

2)if in the example above instead of

```
    TYPE(node)  :: var
```

i would have written:

```
    TYPE(node),POINTER  :: var
```

I guess that if I compiled a 32 bit executable the ALLOCATE statement would allocate the same amount of memory as in the example above. Is it correct?

3)Now lets suppose i declare the type

```
    TYPE :: node
       INTEGER :: int
       TYPE(node), POINTER :: BEFORE
       TYPE(node), POINTER :: AFTER
    END TYPE
    TYPE(node)  :: var
    allocate(var)
```

here (if 32-bit compiled) it would allocate 4 byte for the integer and other 8 for the 2 pointers, for a total of 12 bytes. is that correct?Again how does the computer store the information about the type of variables?

4)In the example (3) if I now write ALLOCATE(var%BEFORE), other 12 bytes are allocated for a variable with derived type node, and the 4 byte of integer type that were allocated for the pointer var%BEFORE (see example 3) are now freed, correct?

THANKS
A.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves so many downwotes. The poster may have some misunderstandings, but his questions are legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This is not covered by the fortran standard. `real` and `integer` do not have to be 4 bytes wide. To ensure that by specifying their precision. If you do not care about the numeric precision, but about the number of bytes, do it like this

```
 !In Fortran 2008
 use iso_fortran_env

 or

 !In Fortran 95
 integer,parameter :: int32  = selected_int_kind(9)
 integer,parameter :: real32 = selected_real_kind(p=6,r=37)

 and

    TYPE :: node
       INTEGER(int32) :: int
       REAL(real32) :: REALfirst
       REAL(real32) :: REALsecond
    END TYPE
```

The compiler is allowed the insert any padding it wants. This is likely ta happen if you mix variables with 4, 8 or even more bytes. To suppress any padding use `SEQUENCE`.

2) The allocated memory would be the same. The compiler also uses some datastructure (it may be just an address, but doesn't have to) for bookkeeping.

3) The bookkeeping datastructure I reffered to is stored in the datatype. It may be just an address.

4) The pointer data structuture can be 4 bytes, but also can be more. The more important point is however, that they are not freed. You must know where to find the allocated space on the heap and you use the pointer for that. It does not matter, whether you use this pointer to allocate new data, or if you point to some existing one.

Note, that bit size of the derived type cannot change at runtime, it is fixed. Another issue  are polymorphic variables, but they must be allocated dynamically for this reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In point (4) there was a typo, I just edited it and I replaced AFTER with node%BEFORE. What I am saying is: if we take for grant that point (3) is doing what you and I are saying, the pointer node%BEFORE occupies 4 bytes (the integer addressing a non-defined yet memory location). if I now write ALLOCATE(var%BEFORE), 12 bytes are allocated on the heap, and those 4 bytes are freed or not? Because if I had written var%BEFORE => var2 (var2 being another variable of type node) instead of ALLOCATE(var%BEFORE),in this case I would have 12 bytes for var2 and 4 byte for var%BEFORE right?

Comment: (int32/real32 and friends were added to iso_fortran_env in F2008.)